# Render captured video chunk to Video Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have this code which captures / records video from camera/audio every second

```
$(function () {
    var handleSuccess = function(stream) {

        var player = document.querySelector("#vid-user");
        var guestPlayer = document.querySelector("#vid-guest");
        player.srcObject = stream;

        console.log("Starting media recording")
        var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm'};
        var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
            console.log("Data available")
            if (e.data.size > 0) {
                // How do I display the captured video to the guestPlayer ?
            }
        }

        mediaRecorder.start(1000);
    };
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
        .then(handleSuccess)
})
```

The question here is how to display the video captured to the `guestPlayer` I am doing this to test out the captured data since that webm chunk `e.data` will be uploaded to a server.

The `e.data` constains

```
data: Blob
size: 26009
type: "video/webm"
__proto__: Blob
size: (...)
type: (...)
slice: ƒ slice()
stream: ƒ stream()
text: ƒ text()
arrayBuffer: ƒ arrayBuffer()
constructor: ƒ Blob()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Blob"
get size: ƒ size()
get type: ƒ type()
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Be sure to use `URL.revokeObjectURL()` when you're done using that blob.